# Annotations on wildcard type parameters in Kotlin

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, bean-validation, javax.validation

I'm looking to create a ValueExtractor for validation and been following documentation here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/valueextraction/ValueExtractor.html

The class in Java requires `@ExtractedValue` annotation on the type parameter:

```
public class ListValueExtractor implements
         ValueExtractor<List<@ExtractedValue ?>> {
```

Is there a way to do the same in Kotlin?

This doesn't compile saying 'Type Expected' next to `*`:

```
class ListValueExtractor : ValueExtractor<List<@ExtractedValue *>> {
```